# LaTeX Error: File `../classicthesis.sty' not found

Tags: errors, lyx, classicthesis

I downloaded a LyX template that uses the style called `classicthesis`. The file was installed from the 'package manager' as an admin and the `classicthesis.sty` file is located in the same folder as my LyX document. However, I still get the error:

```
LaTeX Error: File `../classicthesis.sty' not found
```

when printing to PDF. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: can you try to change `../classicthesis.sty` to `./classicthesis.sty`? `..` sounds like it searches in the parent folder.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I don't know Lyx, but it's rather strange to have this file in your document folder if installed by the Package Manager. What is your TeX distribution?

Comment: [Crosspost](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=27454)

Comment: @Samcarter: Well, it worked - thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

`../classicthesis.sty` means latex searches in the parent folder for the `sty` file. to fix this you have two possibilities:

1. if `classicthesis.sty` is located in the same folder as your document, change `../classicthesis.sty` to `./classicthesis.sty`
2. move `classicthesis.sty` to the folder above your document.